# Node JS not running from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: node.js

I have installed Node Js on Windows 10 64 bit to learn Node JS. When i type 
node -v a cmd window flashes and goes away. When i run the node.exe from the program files, i can run the node commands there such as "console.log". Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you not able to run it in CMD?

Comment: Correct. if i simply type `node -v` a window quickly pops and disappears. same behavior with
 `node myfirstjs` where myfirstjs is the file that has the command `console.log('Node is installed!');`

Comment: Try running ```where node``` and checking that the result is what you expect.

Comment: Press Window + R, put in `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`, hit Enter. Find the PATH variable. Check the node path is there if not add it

Comment: `where node ` gives
C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin\node.exe
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Comment: Environment Variables are set correctly for Node and Npm in the path variable of user and system

Comment: @ankshukla that `C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin\node.exe` means your path variable is _not_ set correctly. The correct path is the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the Node JS Path variable to the top/ahead, worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all these things.  Nothing fixes it.   I've used Node for years on Mac and Linux.  I am going to have to use a vm.

When I run `node server.js` the prompt returns and nothing happens.

Windows11 Sux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling different versions, but ultimately reinstalling Windows did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem yesterday with windows 8 64 bit version.

On a whim, I checked if the node.exe [right click on the icon] properties have "run as administrator" checked in the compatibility tab. It did. But my command window wasn't in an elevated [administrator] prompt.

I just needed to check the version, node --version.

Unchecking run as administrator stopped the window from disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to change the cmd.exe settings to TrustedInstaller. Right click on cmd.exe -> properties -> security -> change the setting there.